# Is there something like fswatch that will work for network mounted drives?

Tags: nfs

On my system, fswatch works great for notifying me about changes to my local file system. But it fails to find new files created in a mounted file system.

Work arounds that I don't like include:
 1. polling the network folder with ls
 2. having the other machine run fswatch and then send the results to the first

Example use case:

A client edits or creates a configuration file over a cellular ftp on MachineA. MachineB, locally networked with MachineA, would like to get the same configuration changes for itself. The client would prefer not sending data multiple times to conserve bandwidth.

Comment: Have you tried `inotify`? I can't test at the moment which is why I'm posting this as a comment. Also, please [edit] and explain exactly what you want so we can give an exact answer (watch dirX for creation/deletion/renaming and do what?)

Comment: looks like inotify is a no go for kernel reasons I suspected. I wouldn't be surprised if fswatch uses inotify.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231243/inotify-with-nfs

Comment: I'm pretty sure that linux doesn't have anything like that. There should be support on the remote side (the server) for instant notification on some actions.

Comment: Any chance you can recommend some apps so I don't have to homebrew it? I would think it's a common problem. Even if it's something as dumb as creating a local copy of the network folder that in in sync.